# Docusaurus i18n & relative image paths

Tags: internationalization, docusaurus

Consider the following folder structure of a Docusaurus project (making use of `@theme/IdealImage`):

```bash
website/
└── docs/
    ├── 01-getting-started/
    │   ├── _shared/
    │   │   └── foo.png
    │   └── index.mdx # contains <Image img={require('./_shared/foo.png')} />
    ├── 02-first-tutorial/
    │   ├── _shared/
    │   │   └── bar.png
    │   ├── index.mdx
    │   ├── dotnet.mdx # contains <Image img={require('./_shared/bar.png')} />
    │   └── nodejs.mdx # contains <Image img={require('./_shared/bar.png')} />
    └── 03-another-tutorial/
        ├── _shared/
        │   └── baz.png
        ├── index.mdx
        ├── dotnet.mdx # contains <Image img={require('./_shared/baz.png')} />
        └── nodejs.mdx # contains <Image img={require('./_shared/baz.png')} />
```

Now, if we want to localize this content using Docusaurus' [i18n](https://docusaurus.io/docs/i18n/introduction) support, we have to copy the images into `i18n/<lang>/docusaurus-plugin-content-docs/current` together with the Markdown content, otherwise the relative paths won't be resolved.

What is the recommended approach of handling relative image paths with i18n, other than copying the images in each `i18n/<lang>` subfolder? Is there any way to configure Docusaurus or the `<Image />` component to look into the original `docs` folder? The only other option I can think of is keeping *all* the images as [static assets](https://docusaurus.io/docs/static-assets) but I'd prefer having them closer to the actual Markdown content that references them.